# looping all properties of a class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Lets say i have some class that holds a structure of data :

```
classA:
@property(strong)NSString *name;
@property(strong)NSString *place;
@property(strong)NSString *age;
```

than i create an instance of `classA` and pass it to some other `classB` ,and this `classB` should save all `A's` values to memory (for example to user defaults) .

How can `classB`, get `classA` as argument, and than without knowing what properties are inside it, just loop over all of them and save them to memory ?

The goal is to add and remove items from `classA` without `B` knowing about them, but `B` can loop them and save them what ever they are .(without using a single array in A )

Comment: Why doesn't class A provide this functionality. It's bad OO design to have class B need to dig down into the details of class A.

Comment: Following up on rmaddy's comment, what happens if classA has a property that's a class? then you gotta follow that one down...

Comment: thanks both! reason for classA existence is that sometimes when you open some new "folder" about someone, its a process, so i would like to create A and when the process is done send it to B for saving. is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html), you can do so.

You will have to import runtime framework as below,

```
     #import <objc/runtime.h>


    id LenderClass = objc_getClass("Lender");
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(LenderClass, &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", property_getName(property), property_getAttributes(property));
    }


  // This class_copyPropertyList will do that purpose.
  objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(LenderClass, &outCount);
```

Comment: if thats the case maybe i do something wrong here,,\